# select cols from another table after left join

Tags: sql, sqlite, left-join

After running this query on df1,

```
"SELECT 'max' type, user, MAX(daytime) time FROM df1 UNION ALL SELECT 'min' type, user, MIN(daytime) time FROM df1")
```

I get something like this:

```
type    user     time
max     a        679..
min     b        12..
```

I have another dataset like this:

```
id      email
a       a@hotmail.com
b       b@hotmail.com
```

I want to join them such that my end result is this:

```
type    user     time      email
max     a        679..     a@hotmail.com
min     b        12..      b@hotmail.com
```

ideally in the same query. I tried this:

```
"SELECT 'max' type, user, MAX(daytime) time FROM df1 UNION ALL SELECT 'min' type, user, MIN(daytime) time FROM df1 LEFT JOIN df2 ON df2.id == df1.user")
```

till here, it doesn't throw an error but as soon as I select the cols from df2,

```
"SELECT email, 'max' type, user, MAX(daytime) time FROM df1 UNION ALL SELECT 'min' type, user, MIN(daytime) time FROM df1 LEFT JOIN df2 ON df2.id == df1.user")
```

I get errors that:

```
PandaSQLException: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such column: email
```

Comment: Please format the queries so that we may read them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must join the result of the union as a subquery to `df2`:

```
SELECT t.*, df2.email 
FROM (
  SELECT 'max' type, user, MAX(daytime) time FROM df1 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'min' type, user, MIN(daytime) time FROM df1 
) t LEFT JOIN df2 ON df2.id = t.user;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cann join only two tables and combine hem into another select

```
SELECT type,    df3.user,     time,      email
FROM
 (SELECT 'max' type, user, MAX(daytime) time FROM df1 UNION ALL SELECT 'min' type, user, MIN(daytime) time FROM df1) df3
LEFT JOIN df2 ON df2.id == df3.user
```